# ReactJS export x (imported as x) not found - When There Is Such File Assigned to x Used as x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, import, export

I'm having troubles using an image I imported from my "dummy_pictures" directory. It seemed to work before I accidently cut all the images form the directory to put them somewhere else instead of copying them, but now reactjs is giving me the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/complex_components/Nav_Bar.js 101:34-41

export 'DEV_IMG' (imported as 'DEV_IMG') was not found in '../../development/dummy_values' (possible exports: DEV_FEED, DEV_MESSAGES, DEV_TRENDING, DEV_USER, DEV_USER_FEED, DEV_VID)


ERROR in ./src/components/complex_components/Nav_Bar.js 108:15-22

export 'DEV_IMG' (imported as 'DEV_IMG') was not found in '../../development/dummy_values' (possible exports: DEV_FEED, DEV_MESSAGES, DEV_TRENDING, DEV_USER, DEV_USER_FEED, DEV_VID)


ERROR in ./src/components/complex_components/Profile.js 18:32-39

export 'DEV_IMG' (imported as 'DEV_IMG') was not found in '../../development/dummy_values' (possible exports: DEV_FEED, DEV_MESSAGES, DEV_TRENDING, DEV_USER, DEV_USER_FEED, DEV_VID)


ERROR in ./src/components/complex_components/Profile.js 52:19-26

export 'DEV_IMG' (imported as 'DEV_IMG') was not found in '../../development/dummy_values' (possible exports: DEV_FEED, DEV_MESSAGES, DEV_TRENDING, DEV_USER, DEV_USER_FEED, DEV_VID)
```

Mapping Relevant Directories:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKV4C.png)

Importing DEV_IMG into dummy_values.js shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmowq.png)

Exported DEV_IMG (and rest) shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0QgF.png)

Importing into profile.js & nav_bar.js and de-structuring as you would:

```
import {DEV_IMG} from '../../development/dummy_values'
```

Exporting both profile and nav_bar as `export default Profile` `export default Nav_Bar`

When I start the app it gives me the react errors, but the image still seems to render when you exit out of the error widget as if it did render and my frontend has no visual errors, and no errors in console.

What am I doing wrong?

- I checked if the frontend had any visible clues that it wasn't rendering the image, but it is (but maybe it's cached?)
- I checked if my importing and exporting was correct
- I checked if the images were in the directory, they are

Comment: Really odd, after touching the file some, and re-writing what I just had the errors went away? It must have been some weird cache thing I don't know about. Can someone enlighten me please?